# ReactもしくはNode.jsで、既存のPDFをフォーマットに使用し、PDF出力を行いたい

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf

### 実現したいこと

現在 フロントエンドをReactでサーバレス環境（Firestore + Cloud Functions）にてWEBの開発を行なっています。
開発の仕様で、既存のPDFをフォーマットに使用して（値をあてはめて）PDFを出力したいのですが、ライブラリ等を調査したところクライアントサイド（React）だけでは既存のPDFをフォーマットに使用しての出力する糸口が見つかっておりません。

Cloud Functions（node.js）も利用しているので、node．js側でも解決できないものか調査を進めているのですが、実現方法ございますでしょうか??

---

### 調査した情報（ライブラリ）とメモ

- React-PDF
  https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf
- PDFkit
  https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit
- pdf-image
  https://github.com/mooz/node-pdf-image
- pdfmake
  http://cly7796.net/wp/javascript/started-with-pdfmake/
  https://qiita.com/maecho/items/071abbb60dcbeabef7a6

Comment: もう、解決しましたでしょうか？

Comment: こちらを参考にPDFの表示とダウンロードまではできましたが、既存のPDFをフォーマットに使用して（値をあてはめて）PDFを出力することはできておりません。https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-create-pdfs-from-react-components-client-side-solution-7f506d9dfa6d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFの編集は非常に手間の係る作業になります。既存のPDFをフォーマットに使う場合、その編集は注釈（Annotation）で値を入力して表示するのが一番楽だと思います。その場合でも、各々の値ごとに出力する位置を0.1mm単位で決める必要があります。もし、フォーマットが少しでも変更になれば、位置がずれてしまうため、位置を全部修正する必要があるのでメンテナンスも大変です。

そのため、既存のPDFを使わずに、HTMLで様式を作成してCloud FunctionsでPuppeteerを使ってPDFに変換した方ははるかに楽にできると思います。

それでも、既存のPDFをフォーマットとして使いたいのであれば、英語版の [Edit *existing* PDF in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073718) という質問が参考になると思います。自分が使ったことがないので保証はできませんが、そこのコメントに書いてある [PDFNetJS](https://www.pdftron.com/blog/webviewer/pdfnetjs-html5-pdf-viewer-and-editor/)を使えば、フロントエンドでPDFの修正ができるのではないでしょうか。

印刷したいだけであれば、pdf.jsとpdf-annotate.jsを使えばできるように思います。

Answer (score 0):

@okeさん
React（TypeScript）＋pdfmakeのフロントエンドをのみで行う方法を知ってます。
最初、pdfmakeはサーバ必須と思いましたがなくてもなんとかできました。

TypeScriptを使わない場合はやりやすいです。
TypeScriptだと型を自分で作る必要がありました。

node（サーバサイド）があってもできますが、なくてもできます。

Reactのプロジェクトの環境は作るの面倒なので「create-react-app」を使いました。

Reactだけではないですが、PDFのは
http://blog.createfield.com/entry/2015/12/16/052221
これが参考になりました。

PDFを出力とはブラウザで表示させますか？
それともダウンロードのみでしょうか？

ブラウザで表示するときは「react-pdf」を使いました。
名前が似てますが、

×これじゃないです
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf

◯こっちです
https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf

とりあえず、私のやり方と同じで良ければ助けられます。
とりあえずやってみてわからなければ聞いてください。

Comment: ちなみにこちらのメリットとしては、どのブラウザでも同じPDFとなることですね。
フォントも何を使うか決めておいてください。フォントの作り方（JS用）もわかりますよ。

Comment: PDFのブラウザの表示とダウンロードはpdf.jsとjspdfにて実現できました。しかし本題の既存のPDFをフォーマットに使用して（値をあてはめて）PDFを出力することはできておりません。

Comment: @okeさん
pdfmakeを使いましたか？今は何にはまってますでしょうか？

サンプルが公式にあるのでそれをみてやることをおすすめします。
http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

Comment: 私がハマったのは、Reactで表示するときに`import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';`
をしたものに
```
  const pdfFonts = require('vendor/vfs_fonts.js');

  const pdf = pdfMake;
  pdf.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
  pdf.fonts = {
    GenShinGothic: {
      normal: 'GenShinGothic-Normal.ttf',
      bold: 'GenShinGothic-Bold.ttf'
    }
  };

  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```
とかですね。